# Render raw HTML from Razor view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 controller function that returns dynamic html using a StringBuilder as a Json result.

This is an quality issue, because I don't want dynamic HTML being returned as a string property in a JSON result.

My goal is to make use of ASP.NET MVC to use .cshtml for example with a viewmodel so that I make an instance of the viewmodel, passing in the results and in the end, return the raw HTML of the view as a JSON result.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what JSON is. Returning raw HTML as JSON would mean returning a single string in a JSON object.

Comment: [Render a View as a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string?rq=1) and add it to JSON.  Very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning an HTML string inside of a JSON object, you may want to consider an action that returns a PartialView directly.

If you can't do this, because you need to return MULTIPLE html strings in one call, then I would advise taking a look at this thread which has a nice static method to turn a rendered view into a String:  [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string).